# Higher order terms in Taylor expansion tend to infinity faster.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, taylor-expansion

Suppose $g$ is a smooth bounded and symmetric probability density function (pdf). Let $\{(X_1,Y_1), ..., (X_N,Y_N)\}$ be a random sample from the joint pdf $t(x,y)$. Further assume $a\to 0$ and $Na \to \infty$ as $N\to \infty$. Define $b=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i}$. Then the Taylor expansion for $g(\frac{bX_1-c}{a})$, with $c$ some finite constant, about $B=E(b|\mathbf{X})$ is 
$g(\frac{bX_1-c}{a})=g(\frac{BX_1-c}{a})+\frac{(b-B)X_1}{a}g'(\frac{BX_1-c}{a})+\frac{(b-B)^2X^2_1}{a^2}g''(\frac{BX_1-c}{a})+...$.
My problem with this expansion is that the order of $a$ increases in the denominator which makes the third term go to infinity faster than the second and so on. Is it possible to use Taylor expansion in this case? If not, what other expansion(s) would work? Thanks in advance!